# Breadth First Search using Adjacency Matrix

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a `BFS` algorithm that returns a `node[]` showing the order of traversal but using an *adjacency matrix*. However, the class I'm given for this task doesn't contain any instance variables in class so I have to implement it all with what is given here. It's traversing every element in the `10x10` grid of vertices instead of finding the shortest path.

```java
    public Node[] breadthFirstSearch(Node start, Node target) {
        // TODO using the adjacency matrix
        LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        ArrayList<Node> visited = new ArrayList<>();
        queue.addLast(start);
        visited.add(start);
        
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node curr = queue.removeFirst();
            if (curr.equals(target)) {
                return (Node[]) visited.toArray();
            } else {
                if (curr.getEdges().isEmpty()) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    queue.addAll((Collection<? extends Node>) start.getEdges().clone());
                }
                visited.add(curr);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then actually ask a question. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: `visited` won't give you the shortest path. You need to track starting with the target node. You could use a field like previous in your Node class or you can use a stack.

Comment: As SomeDude said, `visited` could not help u to find the path. A solution is to assign an int index field to Node, and save the path by index of the Node in a seperated int array, let's call it `path` and then you can go backward from target node index to start node index in `path` array